# Create new javascript object from 2 JSON objects grouped by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I have below dynamic nested JSON object arrays and I wanted to get the desired output with JavaScript grouped by id from both.

First Array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "emp1",
    "location": [
      { "name": "abc", "id": "lc1" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "emp2",
    "location": [
      { "name": "abc", "id": "lc1" },

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "name": "emp3",
    "location": [
      { "name": "xyz", "id": "lc2" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Second array like below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "sub1",
    "id": "11"
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "sub1.1",
    "id": "11"
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "sub2",
    "id": "22"
    ...
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "11",
    "first": [{"name": "emp1"},
              {"name": "emp2"}],
    "second": [{"name": "sub1"},{"name": "sub1.1"}],
    "location": [{"name": "abc"}]
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "first": [{"name": "emp3"}],
    "second": [{"name": "sub2"}],
    "location": [{"name": "xyz"}]
  }
]
```

How to get the desired output like above using javascript/angularjs?

Comment: does there only 2 properties in second array?

Comment: There are more but I only need those 2 elements in my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it using the amazing `Array#reduce` function.

Note that I have named your first array as `a1`, second as `a2` and result as `res`.

```
a1.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
  var existing = arr.filter(function(res) {
    return res.id === obj.id
  })[0]
  if (existing) {
    existing.first.push({
      name: obj.name
    })
  } else {
    var second = a2.filter(function(res) {
      return res.id === obj.id
    })

    var secondObj = second.length ? second.map(function(sec) {
      return {
        name: sec.name
      };
    }) : []

    arr.push({
      id: obj.id,
      first: [{
        name: obj.name
      }],
      second: secondObj,
      location: obj.location
    })
  }

  return arr;
}, [])
```

Here's the working snippet. Take a look!

```js
var a1 = [{
    "id": "11",
    "name": "emp1",
    "location": [{
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "lc1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "emp2",
    "location": [{
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "lc1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "name": "emp3",
    "location": [{
      "name": "xyz",
      "id": "lc2"
    }]
  }
]

var a2 = [{
    "name": "sub1",
    "id": "11"
  }, {
    "name": "sub1.1",
    "id": "11"
  },
  {
    "name": "sub2",
    "id": "22"
  }
]

var res = a1.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
  var existing = arr.filter(function(res) {
    return res.id === obj.id
  })[0]
  if (existing) {
    existing.first.push({
      name: obj.name
    })
  } else {
    var second = a2.filter(function(res) {
      return res.id === obj.id
    })

    var secondObj = second.length ? second.map(function(sec) {
      return {
        name: sec.name
      };
    }) : []

    arr.push({
      id: obj.id,
      first: [{
        name: obj.name
      }],
      second: secondObj,
      location: obj.location
    })
  }

  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using ECMA 2015. Also I am having large list of Ids in both arrays. Can you please post the updated code for ECMA 2015?

Comment: Also @tanmay, It doesn't get the names from second grouped by Ids if there are more than 1. Can you please check the edited question?

Comment: Hi @tanmay! Are you able to fix it if there are more in second based on the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var red1 = [{
    "id": "11",
    "name": "emp1",
    "location": [{
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "lc1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "emp2",
    "location": [{
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "lc1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "name": "emp3",
    "location": [{
      "name": "xyz",
      "id": "lc2"
    }]
  }
]
var b = [{
    "name": "sub1",
    "id": "11"
  },
  {
    "name": "sub2",
    "id": "22"
  }
]
var identication = {}
var result = []
red1.forEach(function(val) {
  if (val['id'] in identication) {
    var t = {}
    t['name'] = val['name']
    result[identication[val['id']]]['first'].push(t)
  } else {
    var t = {}
    t['name'] = val['name']
    val['first'] = []
    val['first'].push(t)
    delete val['name']
    var identity = result.push(val)
    identication[val['id']] = identity - 1;
  }
})
b.forEach(function(d) {
  if (d['id'] in identication) {
    var t = {
      'name': d['name']
    }
    if (!('second' in result[identication[d['id']]])) {
      result[identication[d['id']]]['second'] = []
    }
    result[identication[d['id']]]['second'].push(t)
  } else {
    var t = {}
    for (key in d) {
      if (key == 'name')
        continue
      t[key] = d[key]
    }
    t['second'] = [{
      'name': d['name']
    }]
    var identity = result.push(t)
    identication[d['id']] = identity - 1;
  }
})
console.log(result)
```